# css padding problem?

Tags: css

Following is my css style

```
 .line{
    float:left;
    height:1px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#FFCC;
} 
span.imgLeft{
    float:left;
    padding: 4px 6px 4px 14px;              
}
```

im having many lines like this in my ewebpage, inside two line there is an image , im havng a  problem sometimes my below and above lines are getting more thicker than other , im not getting the reason why this is happening

Comment: @kiran "I'm not getting the reason why" do you have floated elements with `width: 100%;`

Comment: @ Teneff : i didnt put the complete code, i need width to align with the outer width

Comment: Are you clearing your floats? That is usually the first overlooked problem.

Comment: @My Head Hurts : clearing floats means?

Comment: is a property to force not to continue floating next elements.  clear:both, clear:left, clear right.

Comment: @Kiran - Read about floats here at [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).

Comment: @ARTstudio : where is my top part of question > why it is not visible

Answer (score 0):

Check if might be happening that the content between the two lines is not beign generated for some reason, and then if no height is forced inbetween, the two lines are actually shown together, forming a thick line.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing floats means getting the container to spread to size of the content. This can be done by adding a clearfix (an HTML element that has clear:both) or more simply by giving the container CSS property overflow:hidden, if that element has no fixed height.

In your case, you could atleast give overflow:hidden to span.imgLeft. If you give if to .line, you have to make sure the height of the line really is what it is intended to be - currently 1px seems weird if it contains images.